# HereMaps - These credentials do not authorize access. Can't get valid response for Public Transit API

Tags: rest, routes, here-api

I have registered for a public 90-day free trial on HereMaps few days ago and I can't get a valid response for a public transit api. Routing works properly but that API doesn't. I call example request from documentation with my valid credentials:

```
https://transit.cit.api.here.com/v3/route.json
?app_id={APP_ID}
&app_code={APP_CODE}
&routing=all
&dep=41.9773,-87.9019
&arr=41.8961,-87.6552
&time=2017-12-11T07%3A30%3A00
```

after calling it, I receive that response:

```
{
    "Res": {
        "serviceUrl": "https://transit.cit.api.here.com/transit/v3/route.json",
        "Message": {
            "code": "I4",
            "level": "E",
            "text": "These credentials do not authorize access. Please contact your customer representative or submit a request here https://developer.here.com/contact-us to upgrade your account. You can also get valid credentials by registering for a free trial license on https://developer.here.com."
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea, what I'm doing wrong? I thought, that It might be due non-updated database on server-side, bud this seems to not be the problem. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Same problem here, this is the only endpoint which returns this error. I've tried both free account & 90 days trial, happens for both key/code pairs.

Comment: @kozlice I have tried to contact Here customer support, but without any response. I have solved it by using alternative routing - OpenTripPlanner

Comment: @here-developer-support do you have any ideas about this bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please find the reason and explanation below:

https://developer.here.com/faqs#general

How do I evaluate the HERE Platform?
HERE offers a free trial of its web APIs and Mobile SDKs. To register for a free trial, please signup.

Please note that to access the following features we need to whitelist your evaluation app_id. Please contact us to request access to:

Batch Geocoding: allows the user to upload multiple addresses in a single file for geocoding.

***Transit API Advanced Offering: access to advanced features of our Transit API, from early and late departures to real-time next departures and transit isoline.***

Weather API: enrich mapping applications with weather-related data such as weather forecasts, severe weather alerts and astronomical information.

Fleet Connectivity Extension: RESTful web service that enables connectivity between a backend system and a navigation application.

Custom Route Extension: Build custom routes considering your own road restrictions and geometries.

Intermodal Routing: Provides alternative routes combining drive, park, ride and walk functionality, while taking into account real-time traffic and incidents information, public transit timetables and dynamic information.

I hope this helps!

Regards,
Alberto

Comment: Public transport estimated routing (based on timetables) is listed as a standard feature on Plans page, not an advanced one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However I contacted you 1 month ago using email and facebook, but without any response. Now it's useless for me, because I had to choose alternative routing API.

Comment: @kozlice PUBLIC TRANSPORT ESTIMATED ROUTING
Enable estimated transit routing for reaching a destination by public transport. (should work without white listing). The rest of the advanced Transit API features will require it, as stated on the FAQs. prone666 I'm sorry to read this no longer helps you. Hopefully it will help others. HERE is not providing support through Facebook, please use the contact form and email available on the Developer Portal.