# Batch Geocoding these credentials do not authorize access

Tags: here-api

I have been unable to successfully authorize myself to use *HERE Geocoding Batch API*.

I have an API key from using the Request URL version but I am now trying to use the batch and it says I do not have access. After searching on SO I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48956633/heremaps-these-credentials-do-not-authorize-access-cant-get-valid-response-f/49364976#49364976) which seems to indicate that I need to contact *HERE* and have my app id whitelisted. I am currently using the **Freemium version**.

I tried contacting *HERE* using their website was redirected to Stack Overflow by the Sales team.

Request is being sent to https://batch.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/jobs?apiKey=REMOVED&indelim=%7C&outdelim=%7C&action=run&outcols=displayLatitude,displayLongitude,locationLabel,houseNumber,street,district,city,postalCode,county,state,country&outputcombined=true

Valid OAuth bearer token is specified

Response: {“error”:“Forbidden”,“error_description”:“These credentials do not authorize access. Please contact your customer
representative or email locationapi@here.com to discuss upgrading your account.“}

[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWXSo.png)

[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbhEn.png)

Comment: Please explain what contacting HERE means where are you contacting.

Comment: Batch geocoder should be included in the Freemium plan. Could you let us know your app_id, we can have a check on your account.

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport our App Id is DYqt5NJWWPbmjCYqeqEw

Answer (score 0):

Checked with your app_id, it is all normal. Your account is not blocked from using batch geocoding service.

As your are using the oAuth token, please be aware the token is only valid for 24 hours upon generated. For details please check Authentication and Authorization Developer Guide at [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/authentication/dev_guide/topics/using-postman.html#using-postman).

So, please try to generate a new valid token and run the batch job again. Also, if you are using the oAuth token, you don't need to specify the apiKey in your request.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I can confirm that if you have an old apiKey (mine is 1 year old and generated using https://developer.here.com/) the 403 error won't return, but still, all the records sent will be displayed as an error in response  and the response file will have no records

While the new apiKey was created using https://platform.here.com/ and it is working with almost other api endpoints other than Batch Geocoder endpoint